# SaxParser errors with Hibernate and JBoss - conflicting versions?

Tags: hibernate, jboss5.x, saxparser

I am using JBOSS 5.1.0.GA and Hibernate

when I try to connect to the database I get the following errors

```
10:21:03,042 INFO  [Version] Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
10:21:03,049 INFO  [Configuration] configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
10:21:03,049 INFO  [Configuration] Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
10:21:03,077 INFO  [STDOUT] Warning: Caught exception attempting to use SAX to load a SAX XMLReader 
10:21:03,077 INFO  [STDOUT] Warning: Exception was: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader
10:21:03,077 INFO  [STDOUT] Warning: I will print the stack trace then carry on using the default SAX parser
10:21:03,077 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser cannot be cast to org.xml.sax.XMLReader
10:21:03,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(Unknown Source)
10:21:03,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Unknown Source)
10:21:03,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.dom4j.io.SAXHelper.createXMLReader(SAXHelper.java:83)
10:21:03,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.createXMLReader(SAXReader.java:894)
10:21:03,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.getXMLReader(SAXReader.java:715)
10:21:03,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:435)
10:21:03,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1518)
```

then

```
10:21:03,386 INFO  [STDOUT] 10:21:03,382 ERROR [DatabaseManager] Error intialising Hibernate
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1528)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1035)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1017)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1448)


Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser does not implement XMLReader Nested exception: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser does not implement XMLReader
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1518)
```

I have the following dependencies:-

hibernate-annotations 3.4.0.GA
hibernate-commons-annotations 3.1.0.GA
hibernate-core 3.3.0.SP1

I suspect I have a conflict between a jar in the jboss lib and one in my dependencies. can anyone suggest what it might be?

Comment: Do you package hibernate jars in your app? If yes, why?

Comment: we have the hibernate dependencies with scope "compile". if I remove the dependency then mvn clean install fails (it fails on the jaxb-schemagen:generate with a "class does not exist" message for each of the data model classes)

Comment: What if you use a `provided` scope?

Comment: tried that too :-( it won't compile. same reason as before.

Answer (score 0):

I got about same error when trying to run Hibernate 4.0.0.CR6 in JBoss 5.0.1.

The parser needed by Hibernate to parse configuration files seems to be provided by jboss endorsed libraries (*/lib/endorsed/xercesImpl.jar* I believe)and hibernate's xml-apis dependency somehow interfered with them.

Not packing xml-apis .jar in generated archive (.war in my case) turned out to fix the problem.
To do that I overrode the scope of the dependency in the .pom of the project generating the archive (overriding anywhere else wouldn't do because *provided* scope is not transitive):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
  <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.b2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```