# java.lang.AbstractMethodError after upgrading to Hibernate 3.3.2

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jboss5.x, javassist

We have a legacy application that uses Hibernate 3.0.5 and we're trying to upgrade it to Hibernate 3.3.2 (the version that has less impact on the current code).

After updating the dependencies in `pom.xml`, the application deploys correctly, but on queries where there's a lazy association, the following error occurs:

`java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.setUnwrap(Z)V`

The dependencies are configured as follow:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
  <exclusions>
    <!-- 
      Excludes to avoid conflict with JBoss libs
      See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413488/saxparser-errors-with-hibernate-and-jboss-conflicting-versions
     -->
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.b2</version>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javassist</groupId>
  <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.14</version>
</dependency>
```

We've already tried to switch do CGLIB instead of Javassist, but we receive the same error on the equivalent class (`org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer`). There is no stack trace. Here is a picture of the execution stack in the moment the error is thrown.

[image: Stack trace in the moment the error is thrown]

The application is running on **JBoss 5.1.0**.

Any tips about this error? Could this be the wrong version of javassist library?

**EDITED**

- Added JBoss version and corrected javassist version to **3.4.GA**
- Digging further I found that (Z)V means "void return" and "boolean parameter" (http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0286.html)

Comment: Are you using JBoss? If not, what app server? I've seen this issue before (mostly with JBoss) but I'd be interested in knowing that before offering any specific guidance.

Comment: Is that the "full" error message? `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.setUnwrap(Z)V `

Comment: @JStevenPerry, added JBoss version on the question.

Comment: I guess it is caused by conflicting ASM jars, CGLIB depends on ASM. Workaround for CGLIB is a spacial cglib-nodep.jar, it includes correct ASM version with renamed packages.

Comment: @jabliuka, `ASM` and `CGLIB` are not included as dependencies. Moreover, according to [this migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide33) Hibernate 3.3 default is now `javassist`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue very similar to this one, and it turned out to be a JBoss Class Loader issue. JBoss configurations change quickly from one version to the next, and the solution I'm proposing worked for me **using JBoss EAP 5.1.2.**

Here goes.

First, make sure to **explicitly** include the version of Hibernate in your POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Next, you will want to **override JBoss' default ClassLoader isolation** by including a file called `jboss-web.xml` in your `WEB-INF` folder of your WAR file (this same approach should also work if you are deploying an EAR). Its format looks like:

```
<jboss-web>
  <class-loading>
    <loader-repository>
        org.hibernate=my-application.war
        <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
  </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

Where `my-application.war` is the name of your WAR file. Note that the `java2ParentDelegation` set to false may help with other ClassLoader issues (especially with slf4j in my experience).

Finally, JBoss 5.1.x ClassLoader issues are **maddening** to deal with, so I hope this helps. The thing to keep in mind is that the problem is not related to javassist *per se* (and you may consider removing the explicit javassist `<dependency>` in your POM and let Maven resolve it based on the Hibernate `<dependency>`). This is most likely a ClassLoader issue. And the default JBoss strategy for ClassLoading works great most of the time, until you get Hibernate involved. **JBoss pre-Version 6 is deeply tied to the specific version of Hibernate that ships with JBoss, so trying to use a different version of Hibernate than the one JBoss wants to use is a real pain. But it can be done!**

For EAR files, the file is called `jboss-app.xml` and goes in the `META-INF` folder of your EAR file:

```
<jboss-app>
  <loader-repository> 
  org.hibernate:archive=my-application.ear 
     <loader-repository-config> 
     java2ParentDelegation=false 
     </loader-repository-config> 
  </loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

Good luck!

Comment: The error continues despite the configuration. I enabled JBoss classloading log and the JARs being used (javassist, hibernate-core) are (apparently) those in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're saying. Can you clarify? The JARs are in `WEB-INF/lib` but the `jboss-web.xml` file needs to go in `WEB-INF`.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed two answers in one sentence. I did the configuration you suggested in `jboss-web.xml` and also removed explicit `javassist` dependency in `pom.xml`, but it didn't work. 

So I noticed a `javassist.jar` in `$JBOSS_HOME/lib`, and I thought it was not being loaded (because it was configured to not load from parent) and declared it explicitly in POM. The log confirmed the jar was being read from `WEB-INF/lib` but I got the same error message.

Comment: Bummer. JBoss class loading in EAP 5.1 is absolutely hellish. Sorry my suggestion didn't work for you.

Comment: The strangest thing is that version 3.3.1 that ships with JBoss works nicely. Thanks anyway for your help!